# There exists a basis for vector space, such that none of its element lies in its proper subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Exercise**: Let $V_1, \cdots, V_s$ be **proper** vector subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that: there exists a basis for $V$, such that none of its element lies in $V_j$ for $1\leq j \leq s$.

I also showed the following Lemma, not sure it helps or not.

> **Lemma**: Under the same hypothesis, we have that $V_1 \cup V_2 \cup \cdots \cup V_s \subsetneq V$.
>
> *Proof*: This could be done by induction. When $s = 1$, this is trivial. Suppose this is true when $s = m-1$. We are going to prove that it holds for $s = m$:
>
> Step 1: By hypothesis, we could take $\alpha \notin V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_{s-1}$. If $\alpha \notin V_s$, we are done. So we might assume $\alpha \in V_s$. Take $\beta \notin V_s$, then if $\beta \notin V_1\cup \cdots \cup V_{s-1}$, we are done again, so we might assume $\beta \in V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_{s-1}$. We claim that: for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $k\alpha + \beta \notin V_s$, for if $k \alpha + \beta \in V_s$, then $\beta = (k \alpha + \beta) - k\alpha \in V_s$, a contradiction.
>
> Step 2: Then we shall prove that for each $1\leq j \leq s-1$, $V_j$
>   contains at most one such $k\alpha+\beta$. Suppose $V_j$ contains
>   $k_1\alpha+\beta$ and $k_2\alpha+\beta$, then $(k_1\alpha+\beta) - (k_2\alpha+\beta) = (k_1-k_2)\alpha \in V_j$, a contradiction.
>   However, as we have $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we could always find a
>   $k\alpha+\beta \notin V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_{s-1}$. This, combined
>   with step 1, completes the proof of our Lemma.

But I really don't know how to start the exercise, could anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: given linearly independent $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ (where $k < n$) such that none of the $x_i$ are in $V_1 \cup \ldots \cup V_s$, there is a vector not in $V_1 \cup \ldots \cup V_s \cup \text{span}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I believe your hint is an immediate result of the Lemma above, since $\text{span}(x_1, \cdots, x_k)$ is a proper subspace of $V$. Suppose we have picked $x_1$, then we have $x_2 \notin V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_s \cup \text{span}(x_1)$. In particular, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent. Inductively, we could select linearly independent $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ and $x_j \notin V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_s$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.